# MVVMLight - Messenger: Sending message from user control project to the exe project doesn't work

Tags: wpf, user-controls, project, mvvm-light, messenger

I'm using the Messenger class to broadcast messages in the application.
Solution structure:

UserControlProject
- ucContainer
- ucContainerViewModel
- ucLogin
- app.xaml

ExeProject
- MainWindow
- app.xaml

The ucContainer is used in the MainWindow. 
In MainWindow constructor:
`Messenger.Default.Register<LoginSession>(this, OnLoggedIn);`

In ucContainerViewModel constructor:
`Messenger.Default.Register<LoginSession>(this, OnLoggedIn);`

In the ucLogin code behind:
`Messenger.Default.Send<LoginSession>(new LoginSession() { UserName = txtUserName.Text, LoggedInAt = DateTime.Now });`

**Problem**: in the MainWindow the message is not recieved. Why? From the same assembly it's working...in ucContainerViewModel the message is successfully recieved.

**Question** (not related to Messenger): app.xaml exists in both projects. Both contains the  `<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />` line. It's not fully clear for me that it's needed? Where should be the Locator as resource defined - in every project which is using the mvvm light vm concept or only in the application project?

(mvvmlight: 4.1.27, VS2013, ,NET4.5)

Comment: For me messaging is working. Could you explain more details about views and viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

App.xaml is only one file for every startup project (exe). I assume that UserControlProject is only for controls and is not an startup projects. So you could remove app.xaml from UserControlProject. And app.xaml in ExeProject will be used.

The next code

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
```

is saying that

1. Object `vm:ViewModelLocator` will be created once at application start and his unique `Key` for referencing is `Locator`.
2. App.xaml is global resource. Any resources created in it will be visible for all controls and all windows.

So (in MVVMLight strategy) you should declare `<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />` only once at App.xaml. Then you could reference it in user control even at separate assembly as

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
             DataContext="{Binding LoginSession, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
             ... />
```